# YQL for query MLB Live game on time

Tags: yql

I want to develop an App which can monitor MLB live game show on yahoo fantasy sports through YQL.
Has anyone knows if YQL support this target?

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I wouldn't touch YQL with a barge pole these days.

I don't think ANY of the Yahoo API's have a future anymore.  The new owners appear to be raiding what's left of it for anything that might generate a profit, and throwing away the rest.

YQL is now just a small shadow of what it used to be, and I for one am going to be moving everything I have/had using anything Yahoo in the coming months to new platforms.